# Need to create a filter to identify all months with dates inbetween a specified date range - M Language / PowerBI Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, timeline, m

I have a date range column and alongside this I have created copy columns splitting it to have a start date column and and end date column.

I want to select a month from the calendar as a filter so that my data shows data lines within a range than includes the month i would have selected - even when that month is not the start month or the end month.

For example:

Line 1 - start date: 12/01/2023 with end date: 03/03/2023

Line 2 - start date: 14/04/2023 with end date 23/07/2023

Using a month filter - I want to be able to select a month option e.g. 'June 2023', then line 2 above should show as the result since the range is from April to July 2023, or if i select February 2023 then line 1 should show in the result since the range is January 2023 to March 2023.

Thanks for your help in advance

I tried creating a custom column with list of dates within the date range using:
List.Transform({Number.From([TimelineStart])..Number.From([TimelineEnd])},Date.From)

I then duplicated my table and expanded the list to rows, then tried to link my date table to the duplicated table so that (using the item ID as the didentifier) i could then select a month from my date table, which would then in tutn select all dates (i.e. from expanded list) that are under a timeline range.

This didnt work as when i tried to create relationship between my duplciated table and the calendar table i received an error stating i had duplicate values in one of the tables.

Comment: The way I understood it, I would create a date table for the slicer which is not connected to your fact table. Then use that slicer date as filter criteria against the start and the end date in a measure.

Comment: thanks for the response, ah you ve lost me there im afraid. are you able to expain in more detail please when you can? and also an example of the measure? many thanks

Comment: I think the easiest way is, you look up for different examples available on the internet about “disconnected (date) slicer”.  The basic idea is to have NO relationship between the (slicer) date table and any of the date columns in your main/fact table. Then use the selected slicer date, e.g. “MAX(slicerTable[date])”, as the reference for your start and end dates in the main/fact table to filter it accordingly. Edit: this is a simple example https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Using-single-date-slicer-to-filter-three-visuals-by-different/m-p/3181450   Good luck!